# process substitution for output: syntax error depending on how script is called

Tags: zsh, macos, process-substitution

The following script results in error when called directly, but not when called with `. ./test.sh`:

```
% cat test.sh
echo "foo" |
tee >(rev)

% . ./process_subst_test.sh
foo
oof


% ./process_subst_test.sh 
./process_subst_test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./process_subst_test.sh: line 1: `echo "foo" | tee >(rev)'

% echo "foo" |
tee >(rev)
foo
oof
```

What is wrong about the process redirection syntax in the script?

Why results vary depending on how script is invoked?

---

My shell is:

```
% zsh --version
zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)
```

Comment: The `zsh` shell will run scripts with no `#!`-line using the `sh` shell. The `sh` shell does not understand `>(...)`.  See the duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know what that `#!`-line is for, and that it is called `shebang`!